# Read file names from .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filenames

I am attempting to read in multiple file names from a .txt file. Each file names has multiple spaces and ends in different file formats.

When I try this code

```
M = textread('playlist.m3u', '%s')
```

I get the results to be the first string in the first row followed by the next string after the space is the next row ect.

One of the file names in the text file is "C:\Users\user\Music\Pink Floyd\Wish You Were Here (Matersound Gold Limited Edition)\03 - Have a Cigar.flac"

```
'C:\Users\user\Music\Pink'
'Floyd\Wish'
'You'
'Were'
'Here'
'(Matersound'
'Gold'
'Limited'
'Edition)\03'
'-'
'Have'
'a'
'Cigar.flac'
```

How do I simply read in all the files with each file taking up 1 cell in an cell array?

Comment: Can you put up a sample (maybe ~2 lines) `.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textscan` and specify newline `\n` as the delimiter:

```
fid = fopen('playlist.m3u');
M = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n')
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. Could not find anything similar online.

Comment: @amkas90 ... what about in the documentation of the function you were using : `%s Read a white-space OR delimiter separated string.`. That said `textscan` is recommended over `textread` anyway, but the logic is the same.

Comment: @hoki I did look over it, I just didn't see the possibility to read until a delimator of \n. Thank you.